# How to access text inside div tags using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to make a program in Python using Selenium which prints out the quotes from https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day

EDIT: 
I was able to access the quotes and the associated authors like so:

```
    authors = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("""div.col-xs-4.col-md-4 a[title="view author"]""") 
for quote,author in zip(quotes,authors): 
        print('Quote: ', quote.text) 
        print('Author: ', author.text)
```

Not able to club topics similarly. Doing

```
total_topics = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("""div.col-xs-4.col-md-4 a.qkw-btn.btn.btn-xs.oncl_list_kc""")
```

would make an undesired list

Earlier I was using Beautiful Soup which did the job perfectly except the fact that the requests library was able to access only the static website. However, I wanted to be able to scroll the website continuously to keep accessing new quotes. For that purpose, I'm trying to use Selenium.

This is how I did it using Soup:

```
for quote_data in soup.find_all('div', class_='col-xs-4 col-md-4'):  
       quote = quote_data.find('a',title='view quote').text 
       print('Quote: ',quote)
```

However, I am unable to find the same using Selenium. 
My code in Selenium for basic testing:

```
driver.maximize_window() 
driver.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day') 
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN) 
time.sleep(0.2) 

quote = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@title="view quote"]')
```

I also tried CSS Selectors

`print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.col-xs-4 col-md-4')`

The latter gave a NoSuchElementFound exception and the former is not giving any output at all. I would love to get some tips on where I am going wrong and how I would be able to tackle this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
quotes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@title="view quote"]')
```

First scroll to bottom

Answer (score 0):

You might need to write some kind of loop to scroll and click on the quotes links until there are no more elements found. Here's a bit of an outline of how I would do that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/quote_of_the_day') 

while True:

    # wait for all quote elements to appear
    quote_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='view quote']")))

    # todo - need to check for the end condition. page has infinite scrolling
    # break

    # iterate the quote elements until we reach the end of this list
    for quote_link in quote_links:
        quote_link.click()
        driver.back()

        # now quote_links has gone stale because we are on a different page
        quote_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='view quote']")))
```

The above code enters a loop that searches for all of the 'View more' quote links on the page. Then, we iterate the list of links and click on each one. At this point the elements in `quote_links` list have gone stale due to the page no longer existing, so we re-find the elements with `WebDriverWait` before clicking another link.

This is just a rough outline and some extra work will need to be done to determine an end case for the infinite scrolling of the page, and you will need to write in the operations to perform on the quote pages themselves, but hopefully you see the idea here.

Comment: Check out the edit in the post. How would I associate topics with the respective quote and author?